# Confusion about units of angular momentum

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, units

According to multiple sources the SI units for angular momentum are kg * m$^2$ / sec

I am confused about the derivation for this.  Here is what I have done:

$$L = I \cdot \omega \\
  = m \cdot r^2 \cdot r \cdot v(translational) \\
  = kg \cdot m^3 \cdot m/s \\
  = (kg \cdot m^4)/s$$

What are my doing wrong here

Comment: $\omega$ is $\left[ T^{-1}\right]$.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is your definition of the [angular velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity)
$$
\omega=rv \tag{not correct}
$$
is incorrect. We know that $\omega$ has units of $1/s$, but your assertion gives it units of $m^2/s$. The correct definition is
$$
\omega=\frac vr \tag{correct}
$$
which gives the correct units. Using this:
$$
\left[L\right] = [m]\left[r^2\right]\cdot\left[v\cdot r^{-1}\right]=kg\cdot m^2\cdot\frac ms\cdot\frac1m=kg\,m^2\,s^{-1}
$$